# Why is it in SwiftUI, when presenting modal view with .sheet, init() is called twice

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am producing the situation on WatchOS with the following code

```
struct Modal : View {
    @Binding var showingModal : Bool
    
    init(showingModal : Binding<Bool>){
        self._showingModal = showingModal
        print("init modal")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModal.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("TTTT")
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModal.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("AAAA")
        }).sheet(isPresented: $showingModal, content: {Modal(showingModal: self.$showingModal)})
    }
}
```

Every time I press the button in the master view to summon the modal with .sheet, Two instances of the modal view are created.

Could someone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: it seems to be related to transition while animation is in progress). do you have some trouble with it? There is no guarantee, that View will not be recreated any time, even on iOS or macOS. Just don't worry about, don't be dependent on the way how SwiftUI works. State dependent presentation, that is the only paradigm to follow.

Answer (score 9):

I tracked this down in my code to having the following line in my View:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
```

I had been doing it due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61311279/155186, but for some reason that problem seems to have disappeared for me so I guess I no longer need it.

I've filed Feedback FB7723767 with Apple about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug, as of Xcode 11.4.1 (11E503a).
Beware, that if for example initializing view models (or anything else for that matter) like so:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isEditingModalPresented) {
    LEditView(vm: LEditViewModel(), isPresented: self.$isEditingModalPresented)
}
```

the VM will be initialized twice.

Comment: I also ran into this bug as well on Xcode 11.6.  I experimented with having the value set from a button action.  This did not call the .sheet twice however setting the same boolean value on a ObservableObject view model inside that class would cause it to fire twice.  So, I Dispatch to the main queue after 1 second and it only calls it once.  If you dispatch for 0.5, it is called twice.  This is very bizarre behavior indeed but it is a workaround that I found that works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out/remove the init() method from Modal with everything else the same. You should be able to solve the issue of two instances of Modal being created, its because you are explicitly initializing the binding (showingModal) in the init() of Modal. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I just test it out. I commented the init() in the Modal and attach a member obj under it (the member obj print out when init()). It seems the Modal is still being created twice.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have misunderstood the question. I did some experimentation and found out that even though there are two calls going through to init() there is only one sheet instantiated. It may be a bug in SwiftUI. I tested it out by having a .onAppear(){print("OnAppear")} to the button of the Modal. What you will find is two lines printed "init modal" but one line printed "OnAppear".

Answer (score 0):

```
private let uniqueId: String = "uniqueId" 

Button(action: {
    self.showingModal.toggle()
}, label: {
    Text("AAAA")
})
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingModal) {
        Modal(showingModal: self.$showingModal)
          .id("some-unique-id")
    }
```

Ex:

> .id(self.uniqueId)

Add unique id to your .sheet and not't worry :)

`But, do not use UUID(), because sheet view will be represented on every touch event`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the `sheet` and `fullScreenCover` modifiers. In my case it was calling its `content` closure also after showing, hiding the keyboard and typing. To prevent the view from being recreated we can wrap it in a view adopting `Equatable` which is always equal to its instances:

```swift
struct PersistentContentView<Content: View>: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: PersistentContentView<Content>, rhs: PersistentContentView<Content>) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

extension View {
    func persistent() -> some View {
        PersistentContentView { self }
    }
}
```

```swift
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingModal) {
        Modal(showingModal: self.$showingModal)
            .persistent()
    }
```