# SwiftUI having @Environment(\.presentationMode) for dismissing view misbehaving

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have a view with `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>` for a custom dismiss action based on a published value around some logic like this:

```
.onAppear(perform: {
            viewModel.cancellable = viewModel.$shouldPopBack.sink(receiveValue: { shouldPopBackToHome in
                if shouldPopBackToHome {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            })
        })
```

This view also has another option to present a sheet

```
Button(action: {
            shouldNavigateToQRCodeScanner = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Scan QR code")
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }).sheet(isPresented: $shouldNavigateToQRCodeScanner, content: {
            QRCodeScannerView()
        })
```

The problem here is when I have `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` the `QRCodeScannerView` is been initialized twice, when I remove the presentationMode it works fine.

---

**Update**
I've tried the same behaviour in a test project and it's the same

```
struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
@State var isPresentd: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Button(action: {
            isPresentd = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Navigate to Second View")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentd, content: {
                SecondView()
            })
    }
}

}
struct SecondView: View {

init() {
    print("Initialized")
}

var body: some View {
    Text("Second View")
}
}
```

It has the same issue

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: SwiftUI View is a value, it can be created many times by SwiftUI rendering engine, it is not under our control (in majority of cases). So just do not rely on that.

Comment: The problem is it deinit the viewModel and it no longer holds any data

Comment: Solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/61311279/506392